# ASP.NET MVC vs. nTier Separation of Concerns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, separation-of-concerns, n-tier-architecture

with nTier architecture it is common to create a data, business, workflow and ui layer.  In this setup, your data layer and business layers are separated and can be reused by other layers.

In ASP.NET MVC it seems that the model is acting as both the business and data layer as clearly the model is the data and all documentation indicates that business logic belongs in the model.

How is this architecture promoting good separation of concerns when these two layers are mixed?

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between View Models and Domain Models. Domain Models is your application domain. These models can be used everywhere, in any tier and they are usually placed in a separate shared project. Your View Models are just for the UI. They are dependent on your page needs/structure. Let's say you want to create user management page, than your view model may be a class with 2 properties `User` and `List<Role>` where `User` and `Role` are domain models.

And finally, your Data Models usually are just database transfer objects. Entity Framework models are usually used as Data and Domain models at the same time.

---

So, answering your question: you choose your comfortable level of mixing models by yourself. The problem is if you don't want to mix, then you will have quite a bit of model duplications across the solution and you will have to do mapping from one type of model to the other manually or with help of libraries like `AutoMapper`. That's why developers choose some compromise.

Answer (score 1):

> Model–view–controller (MVC) is a software architectural pattern for implementing **user interfaces**. It divides a given software application into three interconnected parts, so as to separate internal representations of information from the ways that information is presented to or accepted from the user. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))

We should take into account that when we talk about ASP.NET MVC, we are talking about "User Interface" so, it is a user interface framework not an application one. In MVC, concerns are separated in three components: Model, View and Controller.

In multi-layer or multi-tier architecture, concerns are mostly separated in Presentation, Application, Business and Data access layers which is an application framework architecture and ASP.NET MVC belongs to the Presentation layer.

All in all, separation of concern is completely achieved if we distinguish between Application and Presentation frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Andrei M is spot on. I agree with the difference between View models and domain models. It may help to think of the M in MVC as a model for your views, and these "view models" should not have any knowledge of where they get their data from. Therein lies the separation of concerns. A controller will broker the exchanges necessary between your domain model and your view models to populate the view models with data. These data exchanges that the controller brokers are often achieved by using another layer such as a repository, infrastructure, or service layer... but not necessarily. In a one-project solution, your "Models" folder might contain a domain model, and then you might have a separate folder called "ViewModels". A controller would fetch data via "the Model" and then populate the view model with the data it "received" from the model. The view model would be the underlying model for your strongly-typed view. One may wonder why a developer might even bother with using a view model if there is a simple one-to-one mapping between domain object and a view. One example is that you may need to "flatten" a domain object and its relationships. Another example might be that for an index or list page, you may need to include search filter; view models greatly simplify accommodating changes to requirements.